# To determine if a quotient ring is also a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R = \mathbb Q[x]/(x^3+18x^2+3x+6)$.
>
> i) check if $R$ is a field and find its characteristic.
> ii) If $R$ is not a field, obtain its quotient field.

i) Let us assume $R$ is a field and $r,s$ belongs to $R$ such that $rs=1$ where $\deg(r)=m>0$ and $\deg(s)=n>0$. Then $\deg(r)+\deg(s)=\deg(1)$  [because $R$ is an integral domain] which is impossible. Therefore $R$ is not a field.

ii) I think we need to show that $R$ has zero divisors and $1$ belongs to $R$ in order to define a quotient field on $R$. Please help me here. I am stuck.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more readable. For future reference, have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to format math expressions.

Comment: yes i was in need of this link. thank you very much.

Comment: @SouravChakraborty : Are you sure that $R$ is an integral domain?

Answer (score 1):

What is $\deg$ in $R$?

$x^3+18x^2+3x+6$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (by Eisenstein's criterion, with the prime $3$) and hence the ideal is maximal. What does this tell you?

For the characteristic, maybe try to show that $\mathbb{Q} \subset R$.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about i) some more. You try to use the degree to prove that $R$ is not a field, but how do you define degree on $R$? What is the degree of the element $f = x^3 \in R$? Does it equal $3$? But $f = -18x^2 - 3x - 6$, which seems to contradict that notion.